# Missing "password.update" file in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

when I enter a new password in the link sent to my [fake smtp testing server](http://mailtrap.io) by the `forgot password` feature provided in laravel 5.7, the page refreshes (instead of routing me to the home page) and the password is not changed to the new one in the database.
While trying to fix this problem, I discovered that `password.update` file is missing on the `views` folder. Please, how can I recreate this file?

NB: The `action` attribute on the password reset form tag is linked to `password.update` file
[here is a screenshot of the form tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm7i4.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default this route should redirect to reset method of ResetPasswordController

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

Check the respective file why it is not going in that method. If its not calling defualt route than you can try creating this new route as above.

Comment: thanks for your response..but the problem is that `update` file is missing in my `views/password` folder

Comment: I think two view files are used in this process one is email.blade.php which is used for showing a form to enter email and then when you click on link the reset.blade.php is used which is used for password reset form. The image provided is the action of form submission. As you show in screenshot the post request url which is used in reset form to submit the new password and redirect it to the /home by default and you can change it according to your need.

Comment: Yes, routing the pages is not the problem, the screenshot is from the `reset.blade.php` file...i.e what happens after the user enters his new password...but the problem is that the new password is not stored in the database..probably because the `update.php` file (responsible for updating the file in the database) is missing...I guess

Comment: Where you found that it is redirecting to update.blade.php file?

Comment: its a wild guess..judging from the `form action` ie in the form submission

Comment: Form action will represent the route on which that form is submitted. What is happening right now when you submit the reset password form? Does it give any error?

Comment: when I submit the form, the page just refreshes...it doesn't even link me to the home page, neither does it update the password...no error message is given

Comment: Check debugging in reset method in ResetPasswordController that it submitting the data to it or not and if its submitting data on this mehod then from where it reverts back?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your last message

Comment: Bro go to reset function in ResetPasswordController and check that it is going inside that function or not as when form will be submitted than it will go to reset function.